# Configure Kibana 4 on IIS7

Tags: iis, elasticsearch, iis-7, kibana, kibana-4

I'm trying to configure Kibana 4 on IIS without any luck on the process. I was able to configure the previous version by using a reverse proxy but with this version I'm not able to make it work.

Has someone of you was able to do it? In that case could you give some details on how to make it work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to install kibana successfully with this guide.

https://www.ulyaoth.net/resources/tutorial-install-logstash-and-kibana-on-a-windows-server.34/

Comment: Unfortunately that link doesn't work anymore, so the answer became wrong. ;) Not sure if SO has something for that. I'm having the same issue (problems with Kibana on iisnode).